# Intel processor peformance

Tags: 14.04, intel, ubuntu-tweak

I have Intel® Core™ i5-3210M CPU @ 2.50GHz × 4

Are there any tweaks to do to get the most out of it on ubuntu?

Thank You.

Comment: Simply... use it :) everything is already optimized, to get the most out of it you simply need to stress it (and probably use applications that parallelize over multiple threads, but that does not depend on Ubuntu).

Answer (score 0):

well you don't have to much because Ubuntu is stable and fast , if you want to improve the boot speed and system speed . then   you can take a look at   over-clock your CPU  (google it )
(you will need a good cooling system something like water-cooled and there are chances that you will ruin your PC )
 get a ram upgrade , shift to an ssd . Ubuntu will harness most of your hardware in a proper way but there are hardware speed limits like CPU speed , ram speed and hard disk speed . these are some factors that will effect you speed . Even the physical hardware factors count too . thats why you have CPUS, rams and ssd of different speeds . i recommend you not to change any thing because you may ruin you hardware beyond repair and remember  **CPU OVER-CLOCKING IS A SERIOUS MATTER DO SOME RESEARCH ON OVERCLOCKING IF YOU WANT TO DO IT**